# Building kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, kernel-modules

I have a 3rd party device driver which I am trying to cross-compile. When I build the driver everything goes smooth but I don't see any driver.ko file, however driver.o file is generated fine and I don't see any error during the build process. I have also tried with the option V=1 and I see following error

```
echo; 
echo "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";
echo "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are         missing.";
echo "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix  it.";
echo;
```

But my kernel configuration is correct and I have tried a simple hello world module with this configuration, in that case I can build my module but still see this error message. Also I can see both the files `include/generated/autoconf.h` and `include/config/auto.conf` in the kernel sources. Still why I am unable to build my driver module.

I am cross-compiling the driver for ARM platform so /lib/modules will not be good in this environment. Secondly here is the output of the build.

```
LD [M]  /home/farshad/Work/CSP/boards/imx6q/ar6k3/ar6003_3.1_RC_Linux_release_[posted_2011_8_19_olca3.1RC_553/imx6build/host/os/linux/ar6000.o                                                          
Building modules, stage 2.
MODPOST 0 modules
make[2]: Leaving directory  `/home/farshad/Work/CSP/projects/phase_1/farshad/cspbox/platform/imx6/mel5/fs/workspace/linux-2.6.38-imx6'
```

As you can see above ar6000.o is built properly without any error, but why ar6000.ko is not being built otherwise it should report "MODPOST 1 modules".
Since ar6000.ko is not being built at the end of the complete build process I also get the following error

```
cp: cannot stat `/home/farshad/Work/CSP/boards/imx6q/ar6k3/ar6003_3.1_RC_Linux_release_[posted_2011_8_19_olca3.1RC_553/imx6build/host/os/linux/ar6000.ko': No such file or directory
2404 make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
```

Which is obvious. My problem is why I am not getting a ar6000.ko in the first place. Searching over google someone also faced this issue and mentioned that running make with sudo resolved it but it brought no luck for me!

I am wandering is there any problem in my kernel configuration (i.e the driver is looking for some configuration setting which I haven't enabled in my kernel, but in that case it should give compiler error looking for required #define), the other point can be that there is a problem with the driver build system, which I am trying to figure out. My cross-compile environment is good as I am seeing exactly the same issue while building the same driver for my (Ubuntu x86) machine!

## Update # 1

Its a 3rd party driver package which also build other utilities along with the driver module. Here is the output of the driver module build process

```
make CT_BUILD_TYPE=MX6Q_ARM CT_OS_TYPE=linux CT_OS_SUB_TYPE=  CT_LINUXPATH=~/Work/CSP/projects/phase_1/farshad/cspbox/platform/imx6/mel5/fs/workspace/linu x-2.6.38-imx6 CT_BUILD_TYPE=MX6Q_ARM CT_CROSS_COM      PILE_TYPE=~/bin/mgc/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/arm-none-linux- gnueabi- CT_ARCH_CPU_TYPE=arm CT_HC_DRIVERS=pci_std/ CT_MAKE_INCLUDE_OVERRIDE=  CT_BUILD_OUTPUT_OVERRIDE=/home/far      shad/Work/CSP/boards/imx6q/ar6k3/ar6003_3.1_RC_Linux_release_[posted_2011_8_19_olca3.1RC_553 /imx6build/host/.output/MX6Q_ARM-SDIO/image  -C   /home/farshad/Work/CSP/boards/imx6q/ar6k3/ar6003_3.1_RC_Linux      _release_[posted_2011_8_19_olca3.1RC_553/imx6build/host/sdiostack/src default
make[3]: Entering directory  `/home/farshad/Work/CSP/boards/imx6q/ar6k3/ar6003_3.1_RC_Linux_release_[posted_2011_8_19_olc a3.1RC_553/imx6build/host/sdiostack/src'
make  -C ~/Work/CSP/projects/phase_1/farshad/cspbox/platform/imx6/mel5/fs/workspace/linux-2.6.38-imx6 SUBDIRS=/home/farshad/Work/CSP/boards/imx6q/ar6k3/ar6003_3.1_RC_Linux_release_[posted_2011_8_19_olca     3.1RC_553/imx6build/host/sdiostack/src ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=~/bin/mgc/CodeSourcery/Sourcery_CodeBench_for_ARM_GNU_Linux/bin/arm-none-linux-gnueabi- EXTRA_CFLAGS="-DLINUX -I/home/farshad/Work/CSP/board     s/imx6q/ar6k3/ar6003_3.1_RC_Linux_release_[posted_2011_8_19_olca3.1RC_553/imx6build/host/sdiostack/src/include  -DDEBUG" modules
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/farshad/Work/CSP/projects/phase_1/farshad/cspbox/platform/imx6/mel5/fs/workspace/linux-2.6.38-imx6'
    Building modules, stage 2.
    MODPOST 0 modules
make[4]: Leaving directory  `/home/farshad/Work/CSP/projects/phase_1/farshad/cspbox/platform/imx6/mel5/fs/workspace/linu x-2.6.38-imx6'
```

Here is the Makefile of the driver module.

```
ifdef CT_MAKE_INCLUDE_OVERRIDE
-include $(CT_MAKE_INCLUDE_OVERRIDE)
else
-include localmake.$(CT_OS_TYPE).inc
-include localmake.$(CT_OS_TYPE).private.inc
endif

export CT_OS_TYPE
export CT_OS_SUB_TYPE
export CT_OS_TOP_LEVEL_RULE 
export CT_PASS_CFLAGS
export CT_SRC_BASE
export CT_BUILD_SUB_PROJ

# this makefile can only be invoked from the /EMSDIO/src base
CT_SRC_BASE :=$(shell pwd)

# export flags for which HCDs to build. Set the hcd driver name in hcd/ in your     localmake.*.inc file.
export CT_HC_DRIVERS
export PDK_BUILD
export HDK_BUILD
export ALL_BUILD
export ATHRAW_FD_BUILD
export BUS_BUILD

# For Linux
ifeq ($(CT_OS_TYPE),linux) 

#make a copy for linux 2.4
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DLINUX -I$(CT_SRC_BASE)/include 
ifneq ($(CT_RELEASE),1)
EXTRA_CFLAGS += -DDEBUG
endif  
export EXTRA_CFLAGS 

CT_SRC_OUTPUT :=$(CT_SRC_BASE)/../output

ifdef CT_BUILD_OUTPUT_OVERRIDE
_CT_COMPILED_OBJECTS_PATH :=$(CT_BUILD_OUTPUT_OVERRIDE)
_MAKE_OUTPUT_DIR :=
_CLEAN_OUTPUT_DIR :=
else
_CT_COMPILED_OBJECTS_PATH := $(CT_SRC_OUTPUT)/$(CT_BUILD_TYPE)
_MAKE_OUTPUT_DIR := mkdir --parents $(_CT_COMPILED_OBJECTS_PATH)
_CLEAN_OUTPUT_DIR := rm -R -f $(CT_SRC_OUTPUT)
endif

ifeq ($(CT_OS_SUB_TYPE),linux_2_4)

CT_PASS_CFLAGS := $(EXTRA_CFLAGS)
_CT_MOD_EXTENSION :=o
ifeq ($(ALL_BUILD),1)
subdir-m += busdriver/ lib/ hcd/ function/   
else 
ifeq ($(BUS_BUILD),1)
subdir-m += busdriver/ lib/ hcd/
else
ifeq ($(PDK_BUILD),1)
subdir-m += function/
else
ifeq ($(HDK_BUILD),1)
subdir-m += hcd/ function/ 
endif
endif
endif
endif

# add in rules to make modules
CT_OS_TOP_LEVEL_RULE :=$(CT_LINUXPATH)/Rules.make
include $(CT_OS_TOP_LEVEL_RULE)
else
#2.6+
_CT_MOD_EXTENSION :=ko
ifeq ($(ALL_BUILD),1)
obj-m += busdriver/ lib/ hcd/ function/  
else 
ifeq ($(BUS_BUILD),1)
obj-m += busdriver/ lib/ hcd/
else 
ifeq ($(PDK_BUILD),1)
obj-m += function/
else
ifeq ($(HDK_BUILD),1)
obj-m += hcd/ function/ 
endif
endif
endif
endif

endif

ifdef CT_BUILD_SUB_PROJ
_CT_SUBDIRS=$(CT_BUILD_SUB_PROJ)
else
_CT_SUBDIRS=$(CT_SRC_BASE)
endif

ifdef CT_CROSS_COMPILE_TYPE 
CT_MAKE_COMMAND_LINE=$(CT_OUTPUT_FLAGS) -C $(CT_LINUXPATH) SUBDIRS=$(_CT_SUBDIRS)     ARCH=$(CT_ARCH_CPU_TYPE) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CT_CROSS_COMPILE_TYPE)
else   
CT_MAKE_COMMAND_LINE=$(CT_OUTPUT_FLAGS) -C $(CT_LINUXPATH) SUBDIRS=$(_CT_SUBDIRS)
endif

makeoutputdirs:
$(_MAKE_OUTPUT_DIR)

default: makeoutputdirs
echo " ************ BUILDING MODULE ************** "
$(MAKE) $(CT_MAKE_COMMAND_LINE) EXTRA_CFLAGS="$(EXTRA_CFLAGS)" modules
echo " *** MODULE EXTENSION = $(_CT_MOD_EXTENSION)"
$(CT_SRC_BASE)/../scripts/getobjects.scr $(CT_SRC_BASE) $(_CT_COMPILED_OBJECTS_PATH)     $(_CT_MOD_EXTENSION)

ifeq ($(CT_OS_SUB_TYPE),linux_2_4)
# on 2.4 we can't invoke the linux clean with SUBDIRS, it will just clean out the kernel
clean:
find $(_CT_SUBDIRS) \( -name '*.[oas]' -o -name core -o -name '.*.flags' -o -name   '.ko' -o -name '.*.cmd' \) -type f -print \
    | grep -v lxdialog/ | xargs rm -f
$(_CLEAN_OUTPUT_DIR)
else 
clean:
$(MAKE) $(CT_MAKE_COMMAND_LINE) clean
find $(_CT_SUBDIRS) \( -name '*.[oas]' -o -name core -o -name '.*.flags' \) -type f  -print \
    | grep -v lxdialog/ | xargs rm -f
$(_CLEAN_OUTPUT_DIR)
endif
endif 

# For QNX
ifeq ($(CT_OS_TYPE),qnx)  
LIST=VARIANT
EARLY_DIRS=lib
##ifndef QRECURSE
QRECURSE=./recurse.mk
##ifdef QCONFIG
###QRDIR=$(dir $(QCONFIG))
##endif
##endif
include $(QRDIR)$(QRECURSE)

endif
```

Comment: Does `ls -l /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` point to the correct directory and do the mentioned files exist in that directory?

Comment: I have given Update # 1 to give more details. Thanks for your time.

Comment: The output before that “Kernel configuration is invalid” message might be relevant. Please post the full compilation log. The third-party driver's Kbuild file may be buggy with your kernel version or configuration. Is it publicly available? What kernel version are you compiling?

Comment: There is no KBuild file, since its a standalone module using my kernel sources. My kernel version is 2.6.38. Please see Updated # 1 for build output & Makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have figured out the problem. I am having square bracket character "[" in the module source directory

```
LD [M]  /home/farshad/Work/CSP/boards/imx6q/ar6k3/ar6003_3.1_RC_Linux_release_[posted_2011_8_19_olca3.1RC_553/imx6build/host/os/linux/ar6000.o
```

Removing this from the path worked well and I got my kernel module object files. I have renamed

```
ar6003_3.1_RC_Linux_release_[posted_2011_8_19_olca3.1RC_553
```

to

```
ar6003,
```

and also tested with

```
ar6003_3.1_RC_Linux_release_posted_2011_8_19_olca3.1RC_553
```

Both worked fine. I was building on Ubuntu 10.04. A colleague of mine has built from the same sources having "[" character in his path on Ubuntu 11.04 and kernel module object file was building nicely, this also suggest the changed behavior of grep / find / awk or such utility among their different versions, which kernel build system is using, resulting in this issue.

Regards,
Farrukh Arshad.